# Movie name with invisible man

Tags: story-identification, movie

Around 6 years back I started watching a movie on television and could never finish.

In the very start of the movie, a male actor wearing a red T-Shirt (let's say his name is Tom) became invisible and no one was able to see him. He was roaming all known places across the city and got to know he is invisible. Until he entered a building where a man was able to see him. Then Tom asked that person what is happening to him.

This is the point where I had to go for work and I was never able to find which movie it was. Stupid me that although the movie looked interesting to me I didn't read its name properly. I just thought it would repeat soon on TV. I know my description is vague and highly incomplete. Anyone has any idea?

The movie was certainly not very old and looked like it was from somewhere in the 2000s (but not 100% sure). The movie is certainly not

1. The Invisible Man;
2. Hollow Man.

Comment: Was he just wearing the red t-shirt when transformed? Was worn clothing visible? In the film, do we, the viewers, see him as completely visible?

Comment: Is it possible that the character was dead & a ghost?  Then no one would see him except some sort of medium.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots We were able to see the character completely including his cloths. And yes, I remember him in T-Shirt from the start of the movie.

Comment: @eshier Dude...that's possible. I never thought this way. But yeah...certainly possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did he look like this?

[image: DVD season 1 cover]

(Note the red t-shirt.)  This is the Sci Fi channel (note contemporary spelling) series ["The Invisible Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invisible_Man_(2000_TV_series))  It originally aired 2000-2002.

Darien Fawkes (the titular character) could control his invisibility, so he could have turned it off on the way into the building.  The building could have been the Agency that he works for.

A couple of notable things about the way invisibility was used in this show:

- Darien could turn his invisibility off and on at will (though it wasn't instantaneous);
- His clothes could turn invisible with him, so when he turned it off he was fully dressed;
- Because the invisibility stuff ("quicksilver") was excreted by his skin, he could turn an object he was holding invisible!
- When he was invisible he could only see using part of the spectrum (downshifted UV light or similar handwavium) so shots from his viewpoint were in black and white.

Comment: This is TV series but I was talking about a movie. But honestly...this guy looks similar. Man, what was I smoking while watching that, huh! Do we have movie as well based on this?

Comment: I thought perhaps you might have seen the 2-hour pilot episode as a TV movie.  It's been a _long_ time but I think that's the one where he's wearing a red t-shirt instead of his later black "agent" look.

Comment: Looks like Red T-Shirt did the trick. I was really unsure whether I should mention that. Thank God I did.